# php files are not working in my enkompass server

Tags: php

When i run .php file in my enkompass server showing below Error message.

**Server Error
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.**

Please help me how to solve this Error. Thanks in Advance

Comment: That can often mean that your php file contains syntax errors; check the file using `php -l <filename>` from the command line

Comment: Usually errors of this kind are logged in the PHP or web server (say Apache) error log. I suggest locating the log and checking what it says. Then post log contents for the error if you need further assistance :)

Comment: I given sample php code like echo "hi" for testing. @MarkBaker

Comment: Where should i locate the Log file..? @cgwyllie

Comment: It's specific to the server setup, but you should be able to tell from the PHP info page, or web server configuration. In a typical cPanel you can view logs from the "Logs" panel, or check the web root for a file called "error_log"